# I get a ServiceActivationException on one of my services while sometimes it works just fine

Tags: wcf

I have a service that retrieves data from a SQL server using Entity Framework. Most of the time it works fine but sometimes it fails with a

> The requested service
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX could be
>   activated." error. To be able to see
>   whats wrong, I have enabled tracing
>   and checked with svctraceviewer. And
>   found out that there is a
>   nullreference exception thats shown
>   ... below are the details of the error
>   I am seeing...
>
> Exception Type:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> Message: The service
>   '/bookadventurewcf/CommonService.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object..
>
> Stack Trace:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()

and so on

So its failing at EnsureServiceAvailable with an Object Refenence not set to an instance of an object.
I am not able to figure out whats causing the error.

Comment: well there must be something in your service code that can fail, obviously. Do you have logging in your own code? If not: you need to add that. Are you **sure** that you're checking all reference objects for != null before using them?? If not: do that! Also: can you put a big `try {......} catch()` around your whole service and catch and log that exception?? Does that help you ??

Comment: marc_s, thanks for the reponse.... I would try all that but same query works sometimes and shows that error sometimes... It should break everytime if there is really something in the code... right? But I will try the logging and see... there is already a try..catch in the code around the whole service.

Comment: I have the same issue.  It seems like the first time the app pool starts it gets this on the first request, but then goes away.  Has been a lower priority of mine to figure out, but my event log annoys me with it.  Stack shows the problem within Microsofts code for me.

Comment: WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/32972148
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/SomeService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  
The exception message is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.CacheBuildResult(

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002386/problems-with-notfound-errors-and-compilation-failures

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error for the reason mentioned below

Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (258187264 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory. As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests. To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.

So check the ram consumption of your server when more than 5% RAM is available your service would have worked fine and when not it throws this error