# Service Activation error after install or update service

Tags: wcf, service-model

I am receiving this exception at the startup of the wcf service:

The Application Log file isn't written in bin folder.

I don't receive this exception on cloud development environment, instead I receive this error in production environment.

The same KB are installed on both environments

Wcf trace

```
 <E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131074</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-09T16:19:45.1760880Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="13464" ThreadID="6" />
<Channel />
<Computer>02SRV0054H</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-IT/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.EventLog.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Wrote to the EventLog.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-130626155754104254</AppDomain>
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord">
<CategoryID.Name>WebHost</CategoryID.Name>
<CategoryID.Value>5</CategoryID.Value>
<InstanceID.Name>WebHostFailedToProcessRequest</InstanceID.Name>
<InstanceID.Value>3221356547</InstanceID.Value>
<Value0>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/19202350</Value0>
<Value1>System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/MessageExchangeService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. ---&gt; System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.CacheBuildResult(String cacheKey, BuildResult result, Int64 hashCode, DateTime utcStart)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CacheBuildResultInternal(String cacheKey, BuildResult result, Int64 hashCode, DateTime utcStart)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String virtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)</Value1>
</ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>



<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131074</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-09T16:19:45.1760880Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="13464" ThreadID="6" />
<Channel />
<Computer>02SRV0054H</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-IT/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.EventLog.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Wrote to the EventLog.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-130626155754104254</AppDomain>
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord">
<CategoryID.Name>WebHost</CategoryID.Name>
<CategoryID.Value>5</CategoryID.Value>
<InstanceID.Name>WebHostFailedToProcessRequest</InstanceID.Name>
<InstanceID.Value>3221356547</InstanceID.Value>
<Value0>System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/35320229</Value0>
<Value1>System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/MessageExchangeService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. ---&gt; System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.CacheBuildResult(String cacheKey, BuildResult result, Int64 hashCode, DateTime utcStart)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CacheBuildResultInternal(String cacheKey, BuildResult result, Int64 hashCode, DateTime utcStart)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String virtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)</Value1>
</ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

Why I am getting this exception ?

Comment: See similar issue at [Problems with NotFound errors and compilation failures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5002386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to recycle your application pool. This might fix the issue. Review the IIS logs for your application pool, too.

See this [link](http://forum.ideablade.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=3292&title=random-crashes-caused-by-a-compilation-error-in-the-entityserversvc).